# How to refer to a split button in instructions?

Tags: word-choice, technical

A split button is a button in a program that the user can click it to do something *or* can click an arrow next to it to access additional functions. Here's an example:

[image: Example split button]

If I am writing instructions that involve a split button, who should I instruct the user to access the secondary functions?

For example, if I needed to write a step in some instructions for the reader to access "Restart" in the above image, how would I write it?

Comment: "Select _Restart_ from drop-down menu".

Comment: I usually refer to it as a drop-down arrow. For example "click the drop-down arrow to the right of the menu and select 'Restart'".

Answer (score 1):

A relatively long-winded way might be:

> Access the drop-down menu next to the Shut Down button and select the "Restart..." option.

A more succinct way would be:

> Select `Shut Down > Restart`

But if you have the option, it might be clearest to simply include the screenshot (as in your question).